# How to apply a function/impute on an interval in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, interpolation, missing-data

I have a Pandas dataset with a monthly Date-time index and a column of outstanding orders (like below):

| Date | orders |
| --- | --- |
| 1991-01-01 | nan |
| 1991-02-01 | nan |
| 1991-03-01 | 24 |
| 1991-04-01 | nan |
| 1991-05-01 | nan |
| 1991-06-01 | nan |
| 1991-07-01 | nan |
| 1991-08-01 | 34 |
| 1991-09-01 | nan |
| 1991-10-01 | nan |
| 1991-11-01 | 22 |
| 1991-12-01 | nan |

I want to linearly interpolate the values to fill the nans. However it has to be applied within 6-month blocks (non-rolling). So for example, one 6-month block would be all the rows between `1991-01-01` and `1991-06-01`, where we would do forward and backward linear imputation such that if there is a `nan` the interpolation would be descending to a final value of 0. So for the same dataset above here is how I would like the end result to look:

| Date | orders |
| --- | --- |
| 1991-01-01 | 8 |
| 1991-02-01 | 16 |
| 1991-03-01 | 24 |
| 1991-04-01 | 18 |
| 1991-05-01 | 12 |
| 1991-06-01 | 6 |
| 1991-07-01 | 17 |
| 1991-08-01 | 34 |
| 1991-09-01 | 30 |
| 1991-10-01 | 26 |
| 1991-11-01 | 22 |
| 1991-12-01 | 11 |

I am lost on how to do this in Pandas however. Any ideas?

Comment: linear interpolation is a local function.  What do you mean applied within 6mo blocks?

Comment: what I mean is linear interpolation applied to a 6-month window (the example illustrated above), but where the 6-month window is NOT rolling (that's why I say 6-month block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is grouping per 6 months with prepend and append 0 values, interpolate and then remove first and last 0 values per groups:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])


f = lambda x: pd.Series([0] + x.tolist() + [0]).interpolate().iloc[1:-1]
df['orders'] = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='6MS', key='Date'))['orders']
                  .transform(f))

print (df)
        Date  orders
0  1991-01-01     8.0
1  1991-02-01    16.0
2  1991-03-01    24.0
3  1991-04-01    18.0
4  1991-05-01    12.0
5  1991-06-01     6.0
6  1991-07-01    17.0
7  1991-08-01    34.0
8  1991-09-01    30.0
9  1991-10-01    26.0
10 1991-11-01    22.0
11 1991-12-01    11.0
```